# creating html template and getting NaN returned from function

Tags: jquery, html, templates

1. I'm trying to create a HTML template for my modals. I attempted to add content to the template, but when I return the content value it prints `NaN` in the modal body instead , and i cant seem to access the object using `content.0`;
2. In the 'getContent' function I intend on appending the content variable with specific HTML elements dependent on server response. is this the best method of achieving this?

**Jquery/Javascript:**

```
function getMessageTemplate(message, instance)
{
    var content = getContent(message);

    var body = 
    '<div class="modal-body msg-body">'+   
        + content +         
    '</div>';

    //more template code....
}

function getContent(message)
{
    var content = $('<div id="selections">'); 
    content.append('<div>message.stuff</div>');
    console.log(content)
    return content.0;                  
}
```

**Inspector:**

```
 <div class="modal-body msg-body">NaN</div>
```

**Console:**

```
 Object { 0: <div#selections>, length: 1 }
```

**--[UPDATE]--**

Ok I did both the suggestions below using `[0].outerHtml` seems to work nicely for the jquery objects, but later when i reference body to create final template I have to use it again.

But do i really need to use it every time I want to reference something that has been appended? Is there a way to append a string without making it an jq-object?

```
 var content = getContent(message);
 var body = $('<div class="modal-body msg-body"></div>').append(content);

function getContent(message) 
{
   var $content = $('<div id="selections"></div>'); 
   $content.append('<div>message</div>');
   return $content[0].outerHTML; 
}
```

Comment: `content.0` is the problem. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: `return content[0].outerHTML; `

Comment: Just want it to reutrn the string ''<div id="selections">   <div>message.stuff</div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem belongs to the line `content.0;`. Use **[`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)** property of dom object, since `content` is a jQuery object you can use `content[0]` to get dom object.

```
function getContent(message)
{
    var content = $('<div id="selections">'); 
    content.append('<div>message.stuff</div>');
    console.log(content)
    return content[0].outerHTML;                  
}
```

```js
var content = $('<div id="selections">');
content.append('<div>message.stuff</div>');
console.log(content[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You don't need to make the code this much complex, you can do it as

```
function getMessageTemplate(message, instance) {
  var content = getContent(message);

  var body = $('<div/>', {
    class: "modal-body msg-body",
    html: content
  });

  // to get it as text use body = body[0].outerHTML;

  //more template code....
}

function getContent(message) {
  var content = $('<div/>', {
    id: "selections",
    html: $('<div/>', {
      text: message
    })
  });
  return content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to have solved how to get the object, didn't realize jqurey objects are accessed differently to the standard ones. Do i have to use this every time i need to append a value tho?

Comment: @Orbitall : check the another answer, that is more better way to deal with creation of dom elements

Comment: Yeah i used that...check my update above...just not keen on all these objects....coz im going to need alot of nested HTML which will require many uses of `[0].outerHtml`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `content.0` line. It would be a better pattern to return the jQuery object containing the `#selections` div and then `append()` that to the element required. Try this:

```
function getMessageTemplate(message, instance) {
    var $content = getContent(message);
    var $body = $('<div class="modal-body msg-body"></div>').append($content);

    //more template code....
}

function getContent(message) {
    var $content = $('<div id="selections"></div>'); 
    $content.append('<div>message.stuff</div>');
    return $content;                  
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is a much better solution to creating templates, and anwsers my second question. Just wish it didn't create another jq-object that requires the [0].outerHtml to access it. Is there a way to append without creating a object?

Comment: There is, but there's no point taking the HTML out of the jQuery object when you can just append that directly. The performance difference is negligible.